# Derivative sigmoid

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If I have $(wx)^2$ my derivative result of $w$ would be $2.(wx).x$, but if I have $(\sigma(wx))^2$, does it means my derivative result of $w$ is $2\cdot\sigma(wx)\cdot\sigma(x)$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In general, you have to use the chain rule. It's perhaps not surprising that, when differentiating something involving the Sigmoid function, at some point you have to calculate the derivative of the Sigmoid function.

Comment: However, if I'm not mistaken, the Sigmoid function has the property that its derivative is
$$
\sigma'(x) = \sigma(x) \cdot (1 - \sigma(x))
$$
This simplifies the calculations.

Comment: With sigmoid you do mean the logistic function? There is not one sigmoid function, but a class of such functions. Another sigmoid function would for example be the atan.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, if d/dx σ(x) = σ(x)⋅(1−σ(x)) then d/dy σ(yx)= x.σ(yx)⋅(1−σ(yx)) ?